# get snippet of html text without creating a DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a html, I'd like to get first 100 characters of text (content without the markups)

I could create a jquery object with the html and use `.text()`.
But the problem is that browsers may load all the images in the html.

So I wonder if there's a way to extract text snippet from html without building a DOM.

**edit**

given a html (just a string of html, not part of DOM yet)

```
<p>my lord</p><img src="some_url"><br>I'm overloaded
```

I could do `$('<div/>').append(html).text().substr(0, 5);` to get 5 characters.

But the img is downloaded by browser, and I don't want that.

Comment: Give some samples you tried.

Comment: please clarify the situation.. given the tags you used, there already is a DOM built..are you using something like phantomjs?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "<p>my lord</p><img src=\"some_url\"><br>I'm overloaded"
s = s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,'').substr(0, 100);
```

Comment: Need to escape the inner double-quote with a backslash \   "...src=\"some_url\"..."   or use single-quote

Comment: @progysm fair enough. Was just the example string though, not the meat of the code. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the image elements and then load it to the dom

Something like

```
var html = "<p>my lord</p><img src="some_url"><br>I'm overloaded";
html = html.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g,"");
var firstFive = $('<div/>').append(html).text().substr(0, 5);
```

Comment: it would give `<p>my ` not the `my load I`